# Warning and Extending User Session

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, session

I use basic authentication for my website and there is an issue when the user is on a form that takes a while to fill out, their session may end and upon clicking "save" the work will disappear because their session is no longer valid.

I tried the following:

set the session timeout to 1 minute in web.config:

> ```
> <system.web>
> <sessionState timeout="1"></sessionState>
> ```

added the following javascript to my page, which is supposed to extend the session every 30 seconds:

```
AlertTimeOut = 30000; // Milliseconds, Alert Message       
WarnTimeOut = 30000; //  Warn Message before 30 sec of session out
setTimeout("WarnUser();", WarnTimeOut);
//setTimeout("AlertUser();", AlertTimeOut);
function AlertUser() {
    alert('Your session has been expired, please save your data outside the system [copy the data in word document].');
}
function WarnUser() {
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes
    }
    if (hours > 11) {
        var tempTime = hours + ":" + minutes + "PM"
    } else {
        var tempTime = hours + ":" + minutes + "AM"
    }
    var ans = confirm("Your login session is about to expire in 5 minutes.Do you want to extend it? - Date: " + tempTime);

    if (ans) {
        var oImage = new Image;
        oImage.src = "tempdummy.gif" + Math.random();
        setTimeout("WarnUser();", WarnTimeOut);
    }
    else {
        setTimeout("AlertUser();", AlertTimeOut);
    }
}
```

here is a snippet of my main.aspx.cs page, after waiting for the javascript pop up to come up 2 times, i refresh the page, and yes, the `session["userid"]` is `null`. I debugged the javascript and it does hit every line of code like it should.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["userid"] == null)
        {
           // the session is no longer valid, i guess the javascript didn't work :(
            //redirect user to an error page
        }
        else
         {
                username = (string)Session["userid"];
                // check user permission, and populate the form here
         }
     }
```

i found quiet a few example online that use similar code to:

```
var oImage = new Image;
oImage.src = "tempdummy.gif" + Math.random();
```

to extend session, but i guess i'm just not understanding how it works. is this an image i'm supposed to have somewhere eon my aspx page? how does it work? because it doesn't for me

---- || ---- || ---- || ---- || ---- || ---- || ---- ||

Update:

I also tried the following:

created a refresh_session.aspx page with only 1 line of code in it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("success");
    }
```

I then try to POST to that page to refresh the seesion (as per this article:http://naspinski.net/post/Automatically-refresh-your-users-Session-behind-the-scenes-using-jQuery-and-AspNet.aspx)

my updated javascript looks like:

```
    AlertTimeOut = 30000; // Milliseconds, Alert Message       
    WarnTimeOut = 30000; //  Warn Message before 30 sec of session out
    setTimeout("WarnUser();", WarnTimeOut);

    function TimedOut() {
        $.post("refresh_session.aspx", null,
        function (data) {
            if (data == "success") {
               setTimeout("TimedOut();", WarnTimeOut);
alert('refreshed');
            }
            else { alert('not refreshed'); }
        }
      );
    }

    function AlertUser() {
        alert('Your session has been expired, please save your data outside the system [copy the data in word document].');
    }
    function WarnUser() {

        var ans = confirm("Your login session is about to expire in 5 minutes.Do you want to extend it? ");

        if (ans) {
            var oImage = new Image;
            oImage.src = "tempdummy.gif";
            TimedOut() ;
            setTimeout("WarnUser();", WarnTimeOut);
        }
        else {
            setTimeout("AlertUser();", AlertTimeOut);
        }
    }
```

the breakpoint in frefresh_session is hit, but then when I refresh my page it is still NULL in my default.aspx :((((((

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors? Try to add a breakpoint in firebug for firefox (or developer tools in chrome /IE -> Hit F12 in your browser). Try to find out if the post call is made and if the respons is indeed 'succes'

Comment: it has magically fixed itself after a few Ctrl-F5 refreshes, it now does hit the refresh_session.aspx page, but the session is still null when i refresh the page again to test it in my default.aspx :( im so confused

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you fetch a image file from the webserver every time the user clicks ok in the pop up so it extends the session.

Do you have an image "tempdummy.gif" on your webserver?

Still I'm a bit confused with the snippet:

```
var oImage = new Image;
oImage.src = "tempdummy.gif" + Math.random();
```

I don't get why they put a random number behind the dummy image name. You'll probably hit a 404 while trying to fetch the image. As far as I know, making a http call resulting in a 404 won't extend the session timeout.

I would try to fetch a real (very small) small image from the webserver and see if that keeps your session open.

Comment: i removed the math.random() and added a full path to a small image on my server, but still the session is not refreshed.

Comment: I was a bit afraid of that, images get served by the static file handler. You can try to make an ajax request to the webserver and check if that would keep your session alive

Comment: i updated my response. can you please take a look if i'm doing it right. it doesn't look like the ajax POST ever gets to the file, as i'm getting the "not refreshed" message